# Optaplanner. School timetabling. Force first lession

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to add constraints to School timetabling example. For example: "all groups should have the first lesson".
I tried EasyScore and Streaming - no success. EasyScore cant finds a proper solution, shuffles lessons a lot. Streaming gave me an error: `Undo for (Lesson(subj...)) does not exist`
Code for Streaming:

```
            from(Lesson::class.java)
                .filter { it.timeslot != null }
                .groupBy({ it.studentGroup }, { it.timeslot!!.day }, ConstraintCollectors.toList())
                .filter { group, day, list ->
                    list.any { it.timeslot!!.number != 1 }
                }
                .penalize(
                    "Student must have first lesson",
                    HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD
                ) { group, day, list -> list.count { it.timeslot!!.number != 1 } },
```

Looks like I'm thinking the wrong direction.
https://github.com/Lewik/timetable
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

update: fixed `==` -> `=!`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, I don't think you're enforcing what you intend to enforce. From what I make from your source code, you penalize every studentgroup's first lesson of the day.

What you should do to enforce the intended goal, is to penalize every studentgroup that does NOT have a timeslot with number == 1 but DOES have one (of the same day) where timeslot number != 1.

So something like :

- join all Lesson.class instances with all Lesson.class instances where the first lesson's **studentGroup** equals the second lesson's **studentGroup** AND the first lesson's timeSlot's **day** equals the second lesson's timeSlot's **day**. You obtain a BiConstraintStream<Lesson, Lesson> this way...
- from this, filter all Lesson.class instances where the first lesson's timeSlot's **number** is less than the second lesson's timeSlot **number**
- then penalise the remaining where the first lesson's timeSlot number differs from 1. That equals penalising all of a studentGroup's days where they have *some* lesson that day without having any lesson that day during the *first* timeslot.

If I understood you correctly, that's what you wanted ?

Comment: yes, there should be `!=`, sorry. But exception remains and I can't understand it.

Comment: I can't understand the third point. At all. And why you provide another constraint? Is my constraint wrong/ineffective? I'm just trying to understand "optaplanner way" :)

Comment: I would avoid this toList alltogether, as I am not sure of everything working properly in that domain. You may be lucky if Lukas Petrovicky may shed some light here.
To answer your more recent comment : in my first 2 points, I selected all Lessons of a (studentGroup, day) combination, with the left one of the BiConstraintStream having the lower timeSlot's number, and the right one having the bigger timeSlot's number. So if the left one's timeSlot number is NOT 1, this means that there is no lesson that day for that studentGroup with a number == 1 (which is what you want to avoid, isn't it ?)

Comment: My intention was not to especially *add* a constraint, my intention was to say how I would implement it. The way your constraint looks like now, doesn't seem wrong any longer to me.But regarding the exception you run into : I suspect that one is caused by a bug in the ConstraintStream implementation (that's why I think Lukas Petrovicky, OptaPlanner developer at RedHat developing the ConstraintStream implementation could say more on this)

Comment: Issue https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2333

Comment: >So if the left one's timeSlot number is NOT 1...

There could be 2-3, 4-5. There could be any pair with the left is lower than the right. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes indeed, you're right. My bad, I didn't think about that situation, indeed. That won't exactly be what you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the real source of the problem, but it's about hashCode. The exception was thrown because HashMap with Object key can't find by that Object.

Lesson class:

```
@Serializable
@NoArg
@PlanningEntity
data class Lesson(
    val subject: String,
    val teacher: String,
    val studentGroup: String,
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = ["timeslotRange"])
    var timeslot: TimeSlot? = null,
    @PlanningId
    val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
)
```

The implementation above will not work. It could be fixed if I remove `data` or add `override fun hashCode() = Objects.hash(id)`. @PlanningId does not help here. Kotlin generates hashCode for data classes and seems it not working with optaplanner (or vise versa)

Comment: You are having hashCode issues, because your hashCode is using planning variables. OptaPlanner entity hashCodes *must not* reference variables, because that would mean the hashCode of an object will be constantly changing. This would prevent OptaPlanner from tracking its internal state.

Comment: Heh, but anyway, I can't come up with no gaps solution

Answer (score 0):

How about using `.ifNotExists()`?

First, convert student group from a String into a class and add `@ProblemFactCollectionProperty List<StudentGroup>` on your solution, then do

```
from(StudentGroup.class)
.ifNotExists(from(Lesson.class).filter(Lesson::isFirstTimeslot),
    equals(this -> this, Lesson::getStudentGroup)
.penalize(...);
```

Comment: Students must have their first lesson each day. Should I multiply join somehow or add another Fact?

Comment: isFirstTimeslot returns true for monday 8 AM, Tuesday 8 AM, ... so for all first timeslots of every day.

Comment: But enough only one first class in whole timetabling. For each StudendGroup - If not exists Lesson in the first Timeslot for this StudendGroup - penalize